# How share linkedin job opportunities and last articles from a likedin page to external website

Tags: linkedin-api

One of my customer would like to share his job opportunities and last articles from his Linkedin page on his external website.
I see that the Linkedin API V1 supported the job searching but now this version is deprecated and V2 API not allows this functionality anymore.
And I didn't find anything about last articles sharing too.

Answer (score 0):

I have written to the support.
This is the response: "we do not allow posts and/or articles to be pulled off of LinkedIn for display on external websites."